# Recipient e-mail validation before creating an envelope

Tags: java, docusignapi

At the company I work on, we use DocuSign to send documents to be signed by our users and use a man-in-middle service that asynchronously communicates with DocuSign after it receives an HTTP request from other services. However, we have faced some issues where our validators said that a given recipient's e-mail is valid but when posting to DocuSign we receive an error saying that is invalid without knowing that this error was due to the e-mail not existing or is in an invalid format. Do you have any document in regards to which validations do you use on recipient's e-mails?

Comment: Why don't you contact DocuSign? You are their customer, I'm sure they will be happy to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

@romalucas, we can't tell what is worng without seeing your API logs, I'd suggest opening a case with us as we may require PII.

Comment: could you send me the link so I can open the case?

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-Do-I-Open-a-Case-in-the-DocuSign-Support-Center